# Correlation column between two column lists as a third column

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming I have the following toy dataframe:

```
Firm         goods        products      

bear   0.1,0.2,0.3     0.4,1.5,9.7
ghost  2.1,3.7,1.5     6.2,2.3,5.5
```

I can save each of the columns `goods` and `products` as numpy arrays by separating the numbers first.

I would like to create a third column that is the correlation between goods and products.

```
df['corrcoeff'] = df['goods].corr(df[products])
```

The final dataframe would look like:

```
Firm         goods        products        corrcoef     

bear   0.1,0.2,0.3     0.4,1.5,9.7      0.91505417
ghost  2.1,3.7,1.5     6.2,2.3,5.5     -0.90641091
```

The challenge here is that the columns `goods` and `products` are not scalars, but are python lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop here, you can use a list comprehension and [`scipy.stats.pearsonr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html):

```
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
df['corrcoef'] = [pearsonr(a,b)[0] for a,b in zip(df['goods'], df['products'])]
```

output:

```
    Firm            goods         products  corrcoef
0   bear  [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]  [0.4, 1.5, 9.7]  0.915054
1  ghost  [2.1, 3.7, 1.5]  [6.2, 2.3, 5.5] -0.906411
```

If you also want the p-values:

```
df.join(
 pd.DataFrame([pearsonr(a,b) for a,b in zip(df['goods'], df['products'])],
              columns=['corrcoef', 'p-value'], index=df.index)
)
```

output:

```
    Firm            goods         products  corrcoef   p-value
0   bear  [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]  [0.4, 1.5, 9.7]  0.915054  0.264295
1  ghost  [2.1, 3.7, 1.5]  [6.2, 2.3, 5.5] -0.906411  0.277622
```

used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Firm': ['bear', 'ghost'],
                   'goods': [[0.1,0.2,0.3], [2.1,3.7,1.5]],
                   'products': [[0.4,1.5,9.7], [6.2,2.3,5.5]]})
```

Comment: one challenge - this worked for me for this toy model. however, I have a dataframe where I have joined several columns together to form the list as a separate column. A = 0.1, B = 0.2, C = 0.3... So goods = 0.1,0.2, 0.3
This involved converting to string and then joining them. do you have a workaround for that?

Comment: @JodeCharger100 the format is you clear, can you make it explicit in the question? Please use the same format as in my answer `df = pd.DataFrame(...)`

Comment: it was quite detailed so I made a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71772094/combine-several-columns-into-an-array-find-correlations-and-save-to-another-co
the challenge I face is in making lists out of several column values